# Concatenate arrays of different sizes row-wise using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, join, merge, concatenation

I managed to join two csv datasets of same size (i.e. same number of columns) row-wise using np.concatenate.

```
combined = np.concatenate((price1,price2))
```

How can I join two csv datasets of different sizes (they contain common headers except that one of the datasets has an additional column) row-wise using numpy?

dataset1's headers : a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k

dataset2's headers : a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j (additional column which is not required for analysis),k

Thanks much.

Comment: what should happen with the additional column? a filler value for the dataset that is missing the column? or removal of the column that is extra?

Comment: column j is redundant for my subsequent analysis/matplot, so it can be removed @ParitoshSingh

Comment: Describe the arrays that you have loaded - shape, dtype, etc.  In numpy we join arrays, not csv files.

Comment: Assuming you are using `np.genfromtxt`, you could use the `usecols` parameter to load dataset2 without the extra column.

Comment: I figured out another approach. I created a subset of dataset2: `dataset2_sub = dataset2[['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k']]`. then used `np.concatenate` for dataset1 and dataset2_sub which would have the same number of columns as dataset1. thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to remove the extra column and then use `np.concatenate`

```
headers = list('abcdefghik')
a = np.arange(len(headers)).reshape(1, -1)
#Output: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

headers_2 = list('abcdefghijk')
b = np.arange(len(headers_2)*2).reshape(2,-1)
#Output: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
#       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]])

col_to_remove = headers_2.index('j')
np.delete(b, col_to_remove, axis = 1) #note that this does not modify original array, returns a copy.
#Output: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10],
#       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]])

result = np.concatenate((a, np.delete(b, col_to_remove, axis = 1)))
#Output: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10],
#       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]])
```